# Use PowerShell to Copy Files to a Shared Drive

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have a script powershell, script сopies database backup files to a network drive.
The script copies only 1 file from 2.
I want to copy all files from local disk D to a network drive, and archive files.
How can I fix this script?

```
$TimeStamp = get-date -f dd_MM_yyyy

$Destination = "M:\networkdrive\folder\BACKUP_10.200.153.55\DATA_" + $TimeStamp

New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $Destination -Force

Copy-Item -Path D:\MSSQL\BACKUP\*.* -Destination $Destination -Force

Remove-Item D:\MSSQL\BACKUP\*.*
```

Comment: Do you want to copy items from that one directory?  What is your end-goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to have to do a loop to find all the files and copy each one. I suggest doing something like:

```
$TimeStamp = get-date -f dd_MM_yyyy
$Destination = "M:\networkdrive\folder\BACKUP_10.200.153.55\DATA_" + $TimeStamp
New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $Destination -Force

gci "D:\MSSQL\BACKUP" -recurse | %{ #loops through al files in that folder and subfolders
    #gets path to file
    $file = $_.Fullname

    #copies file 
    Copy-Item -Path $file -Destination $Destination -Force 

    #removes file from original location
    Remove-Item $file 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will send your backup folder, zipped, to the network store.

```
#requires -Version 5

$Destination = "M:\networkdrive\folder\BACKUP_10.200.153.55\DATA_$(Get-Date -f dd_MM_yyyy).zip"

Compress-Archive -Path D:\MSSQL\BACKUP\* -DestinationPath $Destination -CompressionLevel Optimal -Force -ErrorAction Stop

Get-ChildItem D:\MSSQL\BACKUP -Recurse -Force | Remove-Item -Force
```